# Invoke pthread_create() in linux result in 'Segmentation fault '

Tags: c, linux

Every time when i call method 'pthread_create', run it after compiling the code, it always result in the error 'Segmentation fault', my code listed as below, can any one help me, many thanks!

```
int iLogThreadID;
pthread_t dwLogThread;
iLogThreadID = pthread_create(&dwLogThread, NULL, &logInformation, NULL);
```

method 'logInformation' listed as below

```
void* logInformation(void * info)
{
    char logInfoString[SINGLE_LOG_SIZE];
    memset(logInfoString,0,SINGLE_LOG_SIZE);
    if(gLogFile == NULL)
    {
        return EXEC_ERROR;
    }
    while(g_logThreadStatus == LOG_THREAD_RUNNING)
    {
        if(g_logBufferStartIndex == g_logBufferEndIndex)
        {
            sleep(10 );
            continue;
        }
        if(popLogBuffer(logInfoString) == EXEC_ERROR)
            continue;
        fputs(logInfoString, gLogFile);
        memset(logInfoString,0,SINGLE_LOG_SIZE);
    }
    g_logThreadStatus = LOG_THREAD_TERMINATED;
    return EXEC_OK;
}
```

Makefile

```
CXX= /usr/bin/gcc
LIBDIR=../coapLib
CFLAGS= -I${LIBDIR}
CXXFLAGS= ${CFLAGS} -g
LIBS= -lm -pthread -nostartfiles
OBJ = coapClient.o Block.o CoapMsg.o CoapObserve.o CoapOpt.o Common.o Config.o    IfMatch.o IO.o link.o md5.o cHashtable.o cJSON.o Log.o MsgHandle.o Network.o URIdatabase.o    messagePrint.o ConMsgBase.o ClientMsgHandle.o ClientInterpreter.o 
coapClient: ${OBJ}
    ${CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) -o coapClient ${OBJ} ${LIBS}
coapClient.o: coapClient.c
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c coapClient.c
...
clean:
rm -f *.o coapClient
```

Comment: Run `valgrind` ans see what causes the segfault.

Comment: you can use gdb to know what happened. by the way, how many is SINGLE_LOG_SIZE?

Answer (score 3):

A possible cause (particularly if `sizeof(void*)` and `sizeof(int)` are different on your system) is the signature of the thread start routine is incorrect. It should return a `void*`, not an `int`.

From [man pthread_create](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create):

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

There may also be a race condition in the code if `popLogBuffer()` uses `g_logBufferStartIndex` and another thread is modifying it because it could change between the check in the `if` condition and its use in `popLogBuffer()`.

Comment: i just comment the inner code of method 'logInformation', the same error still reported, so i think the error does not matter with implemention of method 'logInformation', and what does 'particularly if sizeof(void*) and sizeof(int) are different on your system' particularly means with my code

Comment: i'v also change the method type from `int` to `void*`, error still the same, i'm being hopeless

Comment: @stardust, can you post the compiler command you used to build it?

Comment: sorry for replying you after so long a time, now i'v posted the code of my `Makefile`

Comment: @stardust, use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`. That flag instructs gcc to link with the `pthread` library but also defines other macros, like `REENTRANT`, that may be required.

Comment: i'v changed `-lpthread` to `-pthread`, it still doesn't work.And then,add `-DREENTRANT` just after `-pthread`, the result is still the same.btw, `gcc` does not know macros `REENTRANT`

Comment: Make sure you do complete clean and rebuild. Only specify `-pthread`, no need for `_REENTRANT` as the `-pthread` will do that and possibly other things. If it is still occuring try and obtain a minimal program that reproduces it and post it. You may find the bug yourself while reducing your program size.

Answer (score 3):

The `logInformation` function has a wrong prototype: it should be `void *logInformation(void *info)`.

Also you should pass it as follow:

```
int ecode = pthread_create(&dwLogThread, NULL, logInformation, NULL);
```

At last, please note that `pthread_create` returns an error code, which is 0 is everything is OK.